# Google Search Console found huge number of unknow pages from my site, why?

Tags: google-search-console, crawl-errors

I just submitted a web site with only 8 pages, but search console found 500K pages. These pages are not in my site - "UNKNOWN Pages"

##### Example

###### Indexed

- `https://example.com/index.php?21903qcxz4b25bz1fdc`

###### Not Indexed (404)

- `https://example.com/16sjgm8f45gs2173d`
- `https://example.com/1981rthib35vt499`
- `https://mail.example.com/httdups:07399/`
- `https://mail.example.com/httqfps:08120/`
- `https://mail.example.com/9248csnrd3b08decfb0fb54`

I really have  no ideas where the pages come from, or how to fix this? Will such errors harm my site?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Google Search Console, Click on **Pages** and scroll down to **Why Pages aren't indexed**.  There is a column called **Source**.

If it says **Website** then there is a link on your website and you need to fix it.  If it says **Google systems**, then Google has discovered it elsewhere.  With 500K pages, you can't remove them.

However, you should look at your logs on the server to see if you are getting 100s of nonsensical accesses.  The action after that depends on what you find.

**GSC Snapshot**

[image: snapshot]

**Popup Help on Source**

[image: info]

Comment: I had never noticed the Source column before.  Thanks for tip.  However, it is possible that "Website" is another website besides your own.  I have several pages where the source in GSC is "Website" but when I click on the magnifying glass (
"Inspect URL") is clearly identified as a link from an external website.